# Why does JHipster REST endpoint not update foreign keys as the database is updated?

Tags: json, spring, rest, jpa, orm

I'm currently writing a REST endpoint that allows users to POST nested JSON data in order to create and link multiple tables in one JSON payload. To visualize this process, I'll provide a simple example.

[Parent] 1 --> * [Child]

I have a Parent entity, and it is connected, with a OneToMany relationship, to multiple Child entities.

To create a parent and child entity in one API call, the user will POST to /parent:

```
{
    "parent_name" : Dad,
    "childs" : [
        {
            "child_name" : Joe
        }
    ]
}
```

The child will be automatically linked to the parent through the parent's primary key ID, since I added this code to my Parent object.

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
@JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
private Set<Child> children= new HashSet<>();
```

The @JoinColumn operation will add the parent's ID to the child's PARENT_ID column, and I have verified that this works correctly in the database.

The problem is, if I want to send a GET request to see a child's parent (by calling a GET request to the /child/{child_id}), the response body returns the child's parent as null until I restart the application. Once I restart the application and make the same request to /child/{child_id}, I will then be able to see the child's parent (it will give me the parent's ID).

My question is, why is my REST endpoint not updating when I create a new parent + child relationship, until after I restart my app? And is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: Can you add the associated controllers code ? (Both the POST and GET methods). Have you tried removing the cache annotation ? What about the WRITE_ONLY access ?